# Facing issue with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

When i refresh the below page it starts with a white border in the navigation pane rather than showing the entire banner image. The page is loading slight below. How can i over come that ?

Site URL:http://4ktech.in/4k/securitymanagement.html

Comment: do you want to load banner image after your page load complete ?

Comment: Please check after changing the css `@media (min-width: 767px)
.banner.banner_inn {
    height: 640px !important;
    display: inline-table;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    margin-top: -60px;
}`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But i was facing the problem still.

Answer (score 1):

Add `class="affix-top"` on `<nav>` tag as below:

`<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top affix-top" id="nav">`

Comment: Can you add that class for a moment? I will check again